# Planning an architecture in GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to plan an architecture based on GCP cloud platform. Below are the subject areas what I have to cover. Can someone please help me to find out the proper services which will perform that operation?

1. Data ingestion (Batch, Real-time, Scheduler)
2. Data profiling
3. AI/ML based data processing
4. Analytical data processing
5. Elastic search
6. User interface
7. Batch and Real-time publish
8. Security
9. Logging/Audit
10. Monitoring
11. Code repository

If I am missing something which I have to take care then please add the same too.

Answer (score 0):

GCP offers many products with functionality that can overlap partially. What product to use would depend on the more specific use case, and you can find an overview about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/solutions/data-lifecycle-cloud-platform).

That being said, an overall summary of the services you asked about would be:

**1. Data ingestion (Batch, Real-time, Scheduler)**

That will depend on where your data comes from, but the most common options are [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/)  (both for batch and streaming) and [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/) for streaming messages.

**2. Data profiling**

[Dataprep](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/) (which actually runs on top of Dataflow) can be used for data profiling, [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataprep/docs/guides/profiling-basics) is an overview of how you can do it.

**3. AI/ML based data processing**

For this, you have [several options](https://cloud.google.com/products/ai/) depending on your needs. For developers with limited machine learning expertise there is [AutoML](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/) that allows to quickly train and deploy models. For more experienced data scientists there is [ML Engine](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/), that allows training and prediction of custom models made with frameworks like TensorFlow or scikit-learn.

Additionally, there are some pre-trained models for things like [video analysis](https://cloud.google.com/video-intelligence/), [computer vision](https://cloud.google.com/vision/), [speech to text](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/), [speech synthesis](https://cloud.google.com/text-to-speech/), [natural language processing](https://cloud.google.com/natural-language/) or [translation](https://cloud.google.com/translate/).

Plus, it’s even possible to perform some ML tasks in GCP’s data warehouse, [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/#bigqueryml) in SQL language.

**4. Analytical data processing**

Depending on your needs, you can use [Dataproc](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/), which is a managed Hadoop and Spark service, or [Dataflow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/) for stream and batch data processing.
[BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/) is also designed with analytical operations in mind.

**5. Elastic search**

There is no managed Elastic search service directly provided by GCP, but you can find several options on the [marketplace](https://cloud.google.com/marketplace/), like an [API service](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/elastic-saas/elastic-cloud?q=elastic&id=15f9bba7-9808-43fb-b2a3-68a9118aa11d) or a [Kubernetes app](https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/details/google/elasticsearch?q=elastic) for Google’s [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/).

**6. User interface**

If you are referring to a user interface for your own use, [GCP’s console](https://console.cloud.google.com/) is what you’d be using. If you are referring to a UI for end-users, I’d suggest using [App Engine](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/).

If you are referring to a UI for data exploration, there is [Datalab](https://cloud.google.com/datalab/), which is essentially a managed notebook service, and [Data Studio](https://datastudio.google.com/), where you can build plots of your data in real time.

**7. Batch and Real-time publish**

The publishing service in GCP, for both synchronous and asynchronous messages is [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/).

**8. Security**

Most security concerns in GCP are addressed [here](https://cloud.google.com/security/). Which is a wide topic by itself and should probably need a separate question.

**9. Logging/Audit**

GCP uses [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) for logging of most of its products, and provides many ways to process and analyze those logs.

**10. Monitoring**

[Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/stackdriver/) also has [monitoring features](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/).

**11. Code repository**

For this there is [Cloud Source Repositories](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/), which integrate with GCP’s [automated build system](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/) and can also be easily synched with a Github repository.

**12. Analytical data warehouse**

You did not ask for this one, but I think it's an important part of a data analysis stack.
In the case of GCP, this would be [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/).